# How can a crossed dipole (turnstile) antenna be omnidirectional in 3D?

Tags: antenna, physics

A crossed dipole or [Turnstile antenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnstile_antenna) is said to not only be omnidirectional *in the plane of the two dipoles*, but its pattern is roughly spherical, there's no null along the axial (boresight) direction.

There are no monopole waves; in order to couple to plane waves in the far field an antenna must have a dipole moment, but a dipole field will always have a null *somewhere.*

**Question:** How does this actually work? What's the "secret sauce" for getting a spherical radiation pattern from a couple of dipoles?

I'm wondering if there is magic involved somehow. The author of the following does mention having a tool that can make wires longer after cutting them too short though at the time of writing it had been "misplaced" ;-)

> With the initial dimensions, best return loss was at 1.14 GHz, so I pruned the dipoles proportionally to move it up to 1296 MHz. As can be seen in Figure 3, I trimmed a bit too much, so it ended up tuned to 1340, but the Return Loss is still a very good 22 dB at 1296 MHz. I couldn’t find my tool for putting stuff back on, so I figured this is good enough.

cf. [Quick and Cheap Omni Antenna for 1296 MHz from W1GHZ.org](http://www.w1ghz.org/small_proj/Omni_Antenna_for_1296_MHz.pdf) found at http://www.w1ghz.org

[image: Simple Omnidirectional Antenna for 1296 MHz]

Comment: Do you have any simulations or measurements that support the claim?

Comment: (background: there's more involved designs with multiple dipoles that only achieve an approximation, and there's amateur articles out there that claim they build fantastic antennas, but no simulation can reproduce their results. I've grown *extremely* wary of anything that comes out of the amateur radio community, and is an antenna design without any simulation or trustworthy testing.)

Comment: @MarcusMüller despite your qualified trust of amateur radio operators, we'll likely see such simulations or measurements in the answer(s). This is a known thing and answers will explain why it works the way it does.

Comment: I don't mistrust amateur radio operators, at all! It's just that these "I've designed a great antenna articles" are essentially *rumors*: easier to spread than to disprove. If you come with a new design, it's your "duty" to prove it works when publishing it. And [unrepeatable stuff](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/16876/double-cross-antenna-whats-wrong-with-my-model/16880#16880) has been written and published before, in magazines, not the unedited private web pages of a single person.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I can gather from your comments that you haven't actually read it yet.

Comment: I skimmed it. No simulation, no measurement for directivity at all, all that he did was return loss and a very rudimentary evaluation of polarization without a controlled environment. That's nothing, sorry. "The idea is..." is not a reason to trust it is.

Comment: Now, he cites a survey paper, Son et al, "Crossed Dipole Antennas, A Review", 2015, but he literally says he couldn't read the original paper to actually build the same. So, that's like third hand claiming something works.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'll recommend that you take a moment and wait for an authoritative answer to be posted, then you will see how and why this works. Until then it might be helpful to [reconsider your assumptions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/521284/how-can-a-crossed-dipole-turnstile-antenna-be-omnidirectional-in-3d?noredirect=1#comment1339815_521286) btw the linked article doesn't claim 3D omnidirectIonality, this is known to be true. I've asked for an explanation why, that's all.

Comment: I wrote an authorative answer. I don't know how to be more authorative than "doesn't work, made of make-believe, not EM propagation theory".

Comment: @MarcusMüller and others will vote on that answer, and other answers will be posted, and in a day or so we'll understand why this works.

Comment: @MarcusMüller related question [in meta](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7264/102305)

Comment: kind reminder that you said "people will vote, and in a day or so we'll understand why this works". Do you see know how this does *not* work, maybe?

Comment: @MarcusMüller hang on, if the site is sane, math will prevail. If it doesn't, it isn't ;-) Right now I have to [digest and implement this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3829536/284619) but this weekend I'll get back to dipoles.

Comment: Math prevailed, is my point of view, but I'm actually excited to see you implement this!

Answer (score 4):

The author of that paper themselves didn't even fully read the survey paper they're citing: The antenna they replicated was a circularly polarized one, not an omnidirectional one.

When you think about symmetry and what circular polarization means, you'll quickly realize you can't have omnidirectional emission and consistent circular polarization on a sphere; you need the polarization to change, which means that the field can't have the same magnitude in all polarization planes all over the sphere.

In fact, that's a corollary to the pretty intuitive "Hairy Ball Theorem" by Poincaré (the same person of Poincaré Sphere fame, the thing you've learned when studying mixed polarizations).

So, this literally *can't* be an omnidirectional antenna.

Hope this is authorative enough. For general commentary on how to approach papers that claim great things about antennas, but don't offer proof, see my other answer.

---

By the way, here's the figure from the paper 53 that they say they can't access:

[image: Don't fuck with science]

More than 30 dB attenuation at 135° doesn't look like an omni antenna, does it?

The authors themselves don't claim this antenna to be three dimensional omni. Quite the contrary

> A three-dimensional (3-D) plot of the far-field
> resembles a doughnut with an omnidirectional distribution in
> the plane perpendicular to the dipole axis and a figure eight
> pattern in the orthogonal cut.

---

**TL;DR:** doesn't work.

Comment: Hairy ball theorem will show this works if you'd just [reconsider your assumptions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/521284/how-can-a-crossed-dipole-turnstile-antenna-be-omnidirectional-in-3d?noredirect=1#comment1339815_521286) You shouldn't post two answers in rapid succession, this isn't appropriate SE behavior and I've flagged this post accordingly.

Comment: You're hiding the LP power, only showing the CP power. Why not show both, or simply *total power*? These days receiver front-ends can handle full quadrature.

Comment: I'm not hiding anything. This is a CP antenna, you wouldn't use it for LP.  And your sum power argument is no argument – you don't judge antennas by "if you just receive in the right polarization for every single angle, then it's omni"; you judge antennas by "is it omni for the polarization this antenna is designed for".

Comment: Also, guess what you get when you add or subtract RHCP and LHCP ...

Comment: Well, a linearly polarized wave will have equal RHCP *power* and LHCP *power*, and if I subtract those I will get zero, but of course the LP power will still be there.

Comment: no, that's not how CP works: You get CP by adding to a linear polarized wave, a second wave of the same signal, orthorgonally polarized, and phased appropriately. The sign of the phasing determines LH or RH. If you hence add RHCP to an LHCP wave, you keep the in-phase linear component (even with a factor of 2) and cancel the orthogonal.

Comment: Adding *waves* is totally different than adding *powers*.

Comment: Also, you're literally trying to argue against the authors of the original paper (which I don't blame you for, you don't have access to it): *A three-dimensional (3-D) plot of the far-field
resembles a doughnut with an omnidirectional distribution in
the plane perpendicular to the dipole axis and a figure eight
pattern in the orthogonal cut.*

Comment: @uhoh again, adding powers makes no sense, but was what you demanded.

Comment: Adding powers makes total sense if you have a modern receiver front-end that can handle multiple antennas. I've checked Reference 1 from my link now, and I see that Figure 5b validates what is well known to antenna people, the 3D power surface of a turnstile antenna is isotropic. It's a ball, there are no nodes. Obviously the authors agree that adding power makes sense. [Crossed Dipole Antennas: A review.](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7293591) This is a well-known behavior!

Comment: @uhoh I don't really know what your deal is. The people that invented the antenna that you're referring to literally themselves say "this is not 3D omnidirectional", see what I quoted. You yourself notice how any dipole has a null. Every single resource but your paper without measurements nor simulations says this doesn't work. Can we put it to rest already?

Comment: No, *any one dipole* has a null, but in some cases, such as this, *two dipoles* can radiate power roughly isotropically. All you have to do is make one [hairy ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem)'s axis perpendicular to the other's, then multiply the "hair" on one by \$i = \sqrt{-1}\$ before adding them together and then squaring. I don't mind disengaging, let's wait and see what other answers are posted.

Comment: There's nothing to wait for, in all honesty. I wouldn't have posted this answer if it weren't right, to the best of my knowledge, the survey paper that your paper cites, and the original paper. I get the feeling you'd only accept an answer that confirms your bias.

Comment: sorry, last comment (for a while at least), what does the 2nd sentence of the abstract of the above-mentioned IEEE paper say? *They can generate isotropic, omnidirectional, dual-polarized (DP), and circularly polarized (CP) radiation.*

Comment: You might want to read that correctly: Not every single one of them produces has all of these properties... Some do one or the other. The one we talk about is not among those that have the anisotropic property.

Comment: My question only asks "How can a crossed dipole (turnstile) antenna be omnidirectional in 3D?"and "**Question:** How does this actually work? What's the "secret sauce" for getting a spherical radiation pattern from a couple of dipoles?"

Comment: yes, and my answer is "it doesn't work, so I can only explain how it doesn't work, not how it works". Your question is specifically referring to a non-omni antenna (the CP variant of a turnstile isn't omni), and the omni variants are also only approximately 3D-omni (as your wikipedia article itself says).

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a reason why this would yield an approximately spheric wave front.

Unless you have a simulation or measurement that proves working of this, you'll have to assume it doesn't work. It's the scientific way – assume the null hypothesis, unless evidence or theory prove the opposite.

Comment: No, "assume it doesn't work" is not the scientific way. One should assume that one simply doesn't know, or that one has made some implicit assumption that can't be justified.

Comment: I contradict: When I have a new thing that I think could work, then I'll have to assume when considering all my observations with my thing that it *doesn't* work, unless evidence for the contrary is overwhelming. Assuming a "I don't know, so 50/50, maybe?" is not scientific; again, I could simply claim my dipole becomes an anisotropic radiator as soon as I paint flowers on it. Do I get to ask a question "why does flower painting lead to a 3D-omni antenna", too?

Comment: "I don't see a reason why" is because you haven't looked. How are the two dipoles driven? Is it how you've implicitly assumed when you wrote this answer, or did you miss something? Your "it can't work" reaction is similar to my first reaction which led me to post this. I think when you read others' answers you'll feel better. Right now you've just written an answer that says "I don't know" which isn't really a Stack Exchange answer.

Comment: I did not write that. I said "unless evidence to the contrary, and there is none, assume it doesn't work". That's the opposite of "I don't know", I said "I know this doesn't work, and I've found nothing that makes me assume that's not the case".

Comment: @marcus Are you going to combine this with your other answer?

Comment: @VoltageSpike no, I intentionally kept the "general approach" from the "specific approach" answer, as they address different aspects of the question.

Answer (score -4):

### Front matter:

I'd thought this would have a quick answer I could accept, but instead two other answers ([1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/521286/102305), [2](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/521287/102305)) by the same user are of the "it can't work" variety, but they are hard to parse due to a deep and rich array of caveats and distinctions.

So instead I decided to counter all this negativity with a simple explanation just to start things on the right track. I'd prefer to accept a more thorough, authoritative answer, so please feel free to post something more thorough and/or authoritative!

If nobody posts an answer with the math for the 3D far-field power of crossed dipoles driven at 90° in a day or so I'll add it here as well.

### Short answer:

> How can a crossed dipole (turnstile) antenna be omnidirectional in 3D?

and

> **Question:** How does this actually work? What's the "secret sauce" for getting a spherical radiation pattern from a couple of dipoles?

The "secret sauce is that the two diples are ***orthogonal in both the time and space*** domains.

**In plane**, it looks like one dipole no matter which direction you look. At 0°, 90°... etc. you see only one dipole because the other is end-on; at 45°, 135°... you see two, but because they are 90 degrees out of phase there is no angle in-plane where there is a null in power.

**Out of plane** it produces circular polarization. At the poles (axial, boresight direction) it's a pure circular polarization emitter.

There's more at Ta et al. 2015 [Crossed Dipole Antennas: A review](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7293591) (available [here](http://ael.cbnu.ac.kr/lectures/graduate/antenna-engineering/lab-11-crossed-dipole/ta-crossed%20dipole%20review%20%EA%B3%B5%EB%B6%80%EC%9E%90%EB%A3%8C.pdf) as well). It's first reference is G. Brown, “The turnstile,” Electron., vol. 9, pp. 14–17, Apr. 1936. which I can't find a link to.

It has been known for quite some time that these can provide power roughly isotropically. One challenge is of course the mast and/or feed line. That's solved if the transmitter and power source are both right at the feed point!

In 1958 a turnstile antenna was used on the Vanguard-1 satellite one of the first satellites orbited by the US in answer to Sputnik-1 because you'd like to receive its precious data no matter how it tumbled and turned in space! These days satellites can have attitude control systems, but back in the 1950's [satellites could do precious little more than say beep!](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46333/12102)

From [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/18631/12102) to *Why did Sputnik 1 have four antennas?*

> [image: original artwork on the circa-1958 plastic model of a Vanguard series satellite]
>
> **above:** Image from [here](http://www.fantastic-plastic.com/ProjectVanguardSatellitePage.htm) - original artwork on the circa-1958 plastic model of a Vanguard series satellite - antenna pattern is more easily visualize in this representation. More about Vanguard models can be found in [Space Technology from Six Decades Ago: 1:5 Scale Hawk Project Vanguard Satellite](http://www.scalemodelnews.com/2015/09/space-technology-from-six-decades-ago.html).

From [Vanguard 2; NSSDCA/COSPAR ID: 1959-001A](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/nmc/spacecraft/display.action?id=1959-001A):

> Four 30-inch spring-loaded metal rods were folded along the equator of the sphere and would protrude radially outward when deployed, acting as a turnstile antenna. Radio communication was provided by a 1 W, 108.03 MHz telemetry transmitter triggered by the ground station and a 10 mW, 108 MHz Minitrack beacon transmitter that sent a continuous signal for tracking purposes.

Comment: that sadly doesn't answer your own question on how it works, but just, again, *claims* it works.

Comment: Also, again, the photo that you show in your question is not that of an isotropic radiator, which the survey paper doesn't claim, but the paper w1ghz paper simply assumes.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Cheer up, no need for sadness Like it says, "If nobody posts an answer with the math for the 3D far-field power of crossed dipoles driven at 90° in a day or so I'll add it here as well." I'll include the [Hairy ball theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem) as part of it as well.

Comment: cool. and how does that change the fact that the antenna your question specifically asks about isn't a turnstile designed for omnidirectionality at all?

Comment: I'll stop responding and let you leave the last comment. You can [conflate adding power with adding fields again](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/521284/how-can-a-crossed-dipole-turnstile-antenna-be-omnidirectional-in-3d/521295?noredirect=1#comment1339834_521287) or try something new, and if you like, post two more answers as well.

Comment: Been nearly 4 months now and the math still hasn't been added to this answer.......

Comment: @MCG I'm still not sure if it's worth it or not. Two dipoles driven at 90 degrees phase will radiate nearly isotropically but the polarization state varies from circular to linear around the sphere. What happened on this page is pretty ugly; the user decided to "win" by driving several dead-end arguments in a variety of random directions. It looks good if one doesn't look carefully. What would be the point of me writing a thoughtful post if it just gets techno-spammed? I know the answer, I'm happy. What's the benefit to me of further engagement with a noise-generator?

Comment: @MCG I'm remembering where I'd left this a few months ago now; I'd put together several sources about the history of the term "turnstile antenna" and its applications, and checked my conclusions numerically, but I wanted to do the analytical derivation as well and never got to it. Your comment has rekindled my interest, maybe this weekend I'll go back and finish this up. I may post aspects of the results in a different SE first for confirmation, if so I'll ping you with an update. Thanks for bringing this to my attention!